# Which command do I use to find specific file starting from specific directory?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, command

Which command allows to find specific file (for example: test.doc) starting from the home directory?

Do I need to 'su username' first, and then ls->cd or is there specific command doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `find` command:

```
 find /home/foo -name 'test.doc'
```

Or for a case-insensitive search:

```
 find /home/foo -iname 'test.doc'
```

This will output the filename including the relative path. If you want some more detailed information such as the output of `ls -l test.doc` you can do this:

```
 find /home/foo -iname 'test.doc' -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Or just pipe it to `xargs`:

```
 find /home/foo -iname 'test.doc' | xargs ls -lh
```

Comment: @tripleee I feel quite silly that I didn't even know about `find -ls`. Thank you.